# How to keep track of a changed element in a list

Tags: python

For this program, I am using a list with 4 elements. When I change one, I would like to perhaps put it in a variable to know which element got changed. For example:

Original list: ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
New list: ['*', 'B', 'B', 'B']

So with this, how can I let my program know that element 0 got changed?

Comment: Don't change the list directly. Use a function that changes the list, then in this function do whatever else you need to do. Alternatively make your own list class that can respond however you like when it changes.

Answer (score 1):

You can make a subclass of `collections.UserList` and override the methods you will be using to change the list. This will allow you to insert behavior into those methods. If you make sure to call the method on `super()`, the normal list behavior will stay the same. For example, since we don't know exactly what you mean by "how can I let my program know", this just adds a `print()` to each method:

```
from collections import UserList

class NotificationList(UserList):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):        
        super().__setitem__(index, value)

        # do what you want here
        print(f"setting new value, {value}, at index {index}")
        
    def __delitem__(self, index):
        super().__delitem__(index)

        # do what you want here
        print(f"deleting item at index {index}")

    def append(self, value):
        super().append(value)

        # do what you want here
        print(f"appending value {value}")

        
n = NotificationList([1, 2, 3])
print(n)
# [1, 2, 3]

del n[1]
# deleting item at index 1
print(n)
# [1, 3]

n.append(2)
#appending value 2
print(n)
# [1, 3, 2]

n[2] = 10
# setting new value, 10, at index 2
print(n)
# [1, 3, 10]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = ['B', 'B', 'B', 'B']
new_a = ['*', 'B', 'c', 'B']
print([(a[i], i) for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] != new_a[i]])
```

output:

```
[('B', 0), ('B', 2)]
```